# What is the best strategy for running an ansible playbook within an ansible playbook?

Tags: ansible

I have playbook that I've been hacking on for a year and it works OK, but I know it's not great, part of it runs ansible on the target machine with a "command" task.  Because of that, I don't see the output of this task in my ansible playbook.

I need to run this play in the middle of the playbook because it is dependent on a prior task and a subsequent task depends on it (otherwise I'd break it up differently)

I'd like to be able to see the output of all my plays, is there a better way to branch off plays in the middle of a play.

For instance: given a playbook running on HOST_A and HOST_B at TASK 3, suspend running plays, run next plays on HOST_C and HOST_D then HOST_E and HOST_F?

```
- name: update other machines
  command: "/usr/bin/ansible-playbook /etc/ansible/playbooks/other-machines.yml -e 'ansible_user={{ item.ansible_user }}' -l {{ item.ansible_hostname }}"
  with_items: "{{ other_machine_connections }}"
```

Comment: Does the task that you run with `ansible` include `-m command -s 'some commands'`, i.e. you aren't actually running a playbook?  In your last example, is it one play for HOST_A and HOST_B, then run `ansible` command on HOST_C and HOST_D, then final play on HOST_E and HOST_F?  Examples of the plays and commands would help a lot, even if you include dummy code, to understand structure.

Comment: A piece of code would greatly enrich your question...

Comment: @RichVel It's pretty simple and as you describe, except I'm using `ansible-playbook` instead of just `ansible`

Answer (score 5):

If I've understood your problem correctly:

- the `ansible` shell command in the middle could be converted to a simple playbook using the `command` task - let's call this `middle.yml`
- your existing playbook could then directly import this `middle.yml` play (or even a more complex playbook).  In Ansible 2.4+, you would use [import_playbook](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbooks_reuse_includes.html#importing-playbooks), specifically `import_playbook: middle.yml`, or in earlier versions, just `include: middle.yml`.

This processes the whole `middle.yml` playbook as if it was part of the main playbook - you have all the features of Ansible plays (`hosts` etc) and the output appears as part of main playbook.

This answer may need updating depending on your response to my comment above.

Comment: Looking into some of the docs, I discovered something I'd tried before, but forgot about - putting multiple plays inside the same playbook (should have figured that was obvious since it's a playbook!)  but I think that'll accomplish what I want perfectly.  My only problem is that the device I'm running ansible on can't directly reach the devices I want to mess with, but that's not a show stopper.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [Delegation](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbooks_delegation.html#delegation) - you can delegate the execution of tasks to a different host from within a playbook:

```
  - name: enable the server in haproxy
    haproxy: 'state=enabled backend=myapplb host={{ inventory_hostname }} socket=/var/lib/haproxy/stats'
    delegate_to: "{{ item }}"
    with_items: groups.lbservers
```